# In a Q&A feature is it best to allow users to select the Best Answer or...?

Tags: usability, website-design, interface, usability-testing

I'm currently designing a Q&A feature at work and not feeling good about the general direction of how Best Answers are determined. I've always had the notion that in most Q&A platforms the 'Accepted/Best Answer' is selected by the person that initiated the question.

In my case, my team wants to allow the system to determine the best answer based on the number of Thumbs Up (up votes) and I'm struggling with this decision.

Feels like if I'm asking a question and receive answers I should be in control of marking an answer as the best for me.

[image: In this screenshot is my original proposed design that allows the author of the question to mark an answer as the Best Answer]

Any feedback around this?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

**Allow for both options.**

Use this site as a great example of this (it is a Q&A site after all). You can ask a question, and other users can submit answers. In the end, you, the user who asked the question, decides the "selected answer", but that doesn't prevent other users from voting up or down answers. This allows for a personal answer selection as well as a community answer selection.

By having both options, you create a type of "checks and balances" system. Any user who asks a question can mark any answer as being the best answer, even though the answer may not be helpful. By doing this you essentially "invalidate" the trust any user can have your Q&A system. Having a method for the community to voice their opinions on answers helps validate the best answers. The individual asking the question is usually looking for a relatively correct answer, in that they want it to work for them given their circumstances, however; the community is likely going to search for objectively correct answers, because often their circumstances are not the same as the user asking the question. You see this occasionally on Stack Exchange posts, where the selected answer has a moderate amount of up votes, but the second answer which is not marked as the selected answer has a lot more. So which answer is correct? Well both are, given the two scopes of the user asking the question, and the community.

Utilize both the input of the specific user asking the question as well as the input of the community.

Comment: I agree, this site is an excellent example of why it is best to allow users to have an option of manually selecting an answer as well as allowing answers to get voted on.

In my dilemma, the team does not want the ability to allow the author to pick a best answer. 

So imagine Stack Exchange not allowing you to select the 'Checkmark' icon  to signal that in a group of answers that there is one that is the best.

I'm trying to come up with a compelling way to explain why both options are helpful to the overall experience... short of saying "every Q&A forum works this way."

Comment: @Busycloud I've updated my answer giving more reason to go with both options.

Comment: Tori, big thanks! That was perfectly articulated and very helpful. I have designs going into a research study and will have specific questions around this ux. I just didn't want to stand by and allow this feature to only consider the community voice. Thanks again!